# Trying to download a file from Google Drive, but the downloadUrl isn't coming with the metadata

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm starting some development based in Google Drive. Some type of 'Edit in Excel, put it in database'. The problem is: I'm trying to download the file from drive, but I can't get the downloadUrl attribute.

I'm following this page, from Google itself: https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads
It says that I have to get the file metadata and then extract the downloadUrl attribute.

There's something to do with permission? Or some sort of things like that?

EDIT

Here is the code (part of) that I'm using.
First, a function that is showed on Google's page

```
function downloadFile($service, $file) {
    $downloadUrl = $file->getDownloadUrl();
    if ($downloadUrl) {
        $request = new Google_HttpRequest($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
        $httpRequest = Google_Client::$io->authenticatedRequest($request);
        if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
            return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
        }
    }
}
```

The rest of the code still as the example:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
// Get your credentials from the APIs Console
$client->setClientId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$client->setClientSecret('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

$service = new Google_DriveService($client);
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

//Request authorization
print "Please visit:\n$authUrl\n\n";
print "Please enter the auth code:\n";
$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

// Exchange authorization code for access token
$accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

//Retrive a file
$file = new Google_DriveFile();

$file->setDownloadUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{fileID}");
$requestedFile = json_decode(downloadFile($service, $file));
print_r($requestedFile);
```

When printed, I can't see the downloadUrl attribute. Of course, I can't access it too!

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: @SteveP. There you go! ;D I hope it'll be useful!

Comment: Why are you setting the download url?

Comment: If this is a Google Spreadsheet or Doc you will not have a downloadUrl, instead you need to look at the correct exportLinks for your required file type.

Comment: @AliAfshar I've already tried this, unsucessfully. Give me a time out error!

Comment: @BurcuDogan If I don't, it returns a 'non-valid' object. If you may look closer at the File Drive declaration, you'll see that nothing has been passed to the construct.

Comment: You cannot download the file contents by making a request to https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{fileID}. You need to download one of the export links. If the file is too large, maybe you need to set the timeout to a higher level. Could you try it with a small excel sheet first if size is the case?

Comment: @BurcuDogan I use this googleapis.com/drive/v2/files{fileID} to retrieve the metadata. Then, I'd hope to get the urlDownload attribute, or even some of the exportLinks.

They aren't in timeout anymore. I solve this problem, but... I'm using the PHP function file_get_contents against one of the export links, and it returns the redirection page in HTML, instead of the doc.  

Any idea why? Should I use another function? Which one?

Comment: How do you pass the authorization header to the file_get_contents? If you dont authorize the request, it'll give you a 401 and will redirect you an error page.

Comment: @BurcuDogan Thanks to you, I realize that I was having a misunderstood over the documentation. I'm using a function now to get the file metadata...  
    $service->files->get($fileId);  
... and the function described above to get the archieve. Thank you, so much. I get to this conclusion over the comment you made above (May, 23). Thanks, again... :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my [blog](http://flashum.com/?q=drupal_blog#simple-table-of-contents-25) I go into detail about how to get the authorization code and then get a directory listing.  Each file in the listing has metadata, including the downloadUrl attribute.  This is covered in the blog as well [here.](http://flashum.com/?q=drupal_blog#simple-table-of-contents-29)

I am also trying to download a file but am having a different problem, but you might find it of use [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430142/google-drive-sdk-downloadfile-what-does-it-do).

Comment: I think in SO the best practice is to write the code here, not to redirect to another page, except for reference

Comment: ..and the blog link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
/** @var GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response $content */
$content = $service->files->get($googleDriveId, ['alt' => 'media']);
```

I also recommend you use sdk v2, that has integration with guzzle. And this code will return GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response instead of string.